# Conditionally insert multiple data rows into multiple Postgres tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

I have multiple rows of data. And this is just some made up data in order to make an easy example.

- The data has `name`, `age` and `location`.
- I want to insert the data into two tables, `persons` and `locations`, where `locations` has a FK to `persons`.
- Nothing should be inserted if there already is a person with that name, or if the age is below 18.
- I need to use `COPY` (in my real world example I'm using NPQSQL for .NET and I think that's the fastest way of inserting a lot of data).

So I'll do the following in a transaction (not 100% sure on the syntax, not on my computer right now):

```
-- Create a temp table 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_x;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_x
(
    name TEXT,
    age INTEGER,
    location TEXT
);

-- Read the data into the temp table
COPY tmp_x (name, age) FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY);

-- Conditionally insert the data into persons
WITH insertedPersons AS (
    INSERT INTO persons (name, age)
    SELECT name, age 
    FROM tmp_x tmp
    LEFT JOIN persons p ON p.name = tmp.name 
    WHERE 
        p IS NULL
        AND tmp.age >= 18
    RETURNING id, name
),

-- Use the generated ids to insert the relational data into locations
WITH insertedLocations AS (
    INSERT INTO locations (personid, location)
    SELECT ip.id, tmp.location 
    FROM tmp_x tmp
    INNER JOIN insertedPersons ip ON ip.name = tmp.name
),
DROP TABLE tmp_x;
```

1. Is there a better/easier/more efficient way to do this?
2. Is there a better way to "link" the inserts instead of `INNER JOIN insertedPersons ip ON ip.name = tmp.name`. What if `name` wasn't unique? Can I update `tmp_x` with the new person ids and use that?

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable.  However, as phrased, the question is too broad.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree that question #1 is very broad. But I think #2 is pretty concrete: How can I insert the dependent data if `name` isn't unique?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Or maybe it's just a question of adding more to the join: `INNER JOIN insertedPersons ip ON (ip.name = tmp.name AND ip.age = tmp.age)`?